# creating a new child theme

Tags: child-theme

When I create a child theme I have to create it all under the unzipped wordpress/theme file?  Will it automatically add itself to my web page or does something have to be done to activate it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're attempting to develop your own child theme, these links should be useful.

- [WordPress Codex (Child Themes)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)
- [Child Themes Basics and Creating Child Themes in WordPress](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/child-themes-basics-and-creating-child-themes-in-wordpress/)

If you're trying to install a child theme that someone else created, this link should be useful.

- [How to Install a WordPress Child Theme](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-install-a-wordpress-child-theme/)